# Creating a dynamic image in HTML with a transparent background

Tags: html, css, background-color

Let's say I'm making a Valentine's Day app. I want a heart to fill up with pink from 0 to 100 to show one's love for another.

The height of the image will be 102 pixels, and for every % someone is "in love", we will creep up a single-pixel height line.

My approach is as follows: go into Photoshop and remove the 'background' of the inside of the heart, so that the inside is now transparent. The area of the surrounding heart will be painted white. Put on a site with a white background. Put the image on a 102 x (whatever) div, then put another div inside, whose background color is pink. It's then a simple matter of increasing the child div's height.

This is nice, but I can only use it on sites which have a white background, because it's the white that's preventing the area from turning pink. In short, I need a way to fill up this heart while being able to change the background color of the web page.

Comment: Check out SVG images... Browser dependent though...

Comment: how about the using a transparent image with the background color

Comment: @Rene: A simple website, and no, canvas and SVG are too complicated for this. I could need five of these on each page and it would still have to work nicely. They do also bring some compatibility issues. I could never use 100 images; for pride and for maintainability.

Comment: @VaelVictus Remember to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12571250/144665).

Comment: I will accept after a few days if it seems that no one can provide a solution that will be what I need. You showed me a great method, but I still need a transparent middle and background to the heart. And specifically not just for hearts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the heart as you normally would making the background transparent and fill in the center. Use that as the background image of a div and position it at the bottom.

The example below shows a heart at 40%.

HTML

```
<div class="heart-wrap">
    <div class="heart" style="height: 40px; margin-top: 60px;"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.heart,
.heart-wrap {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.heart {
    background: transparent left bottom url('/heart.png');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UFBjh/

Demo2: http://jsfiddle.net/L5uDp/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. I see the fiddle, but it seems the triangle's getting cut off at the top and generally it's just not doing what I'd expect. Here, I'd expect the area around the triangle to be white, and the inside of the triangle to be filling up with green until 40% height. The whole thing is just green, in chrome and firefox.

Comment: @VaelVictus http://jsfiddle.net/L5uDp/ - found a semi-transparent heart which works nicely.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean now. Still, if I had to change the color of the heart to another color, I couldn't do it, correct?

Comment: No, not like you described it in your OP. For that you would have to use the not so x-browser CS3 option below.

Comment: I'll accept because I doubt there's a way to do this without SVG or canvas. You've done the most and have at least showed me an alternative way to get certain images to work how I'd like them to, if I ever need to. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this demo. This is probably what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/Rhpyp/

The solution involves *drawing* out the heart using CSS3 using the technique mentioned in http://www.webfroze.com/css/heart-shape/

And then having an outer div handle the partial hiding of the heart as needed.

[image]

The color of the heart as well as the DIV that is used for partially hiding it is editable via CSS.

Comment: That would actually be very useful if I were building this app, but it was just an example. Still, thanks for the effort.

Comment: NP, I did little. Credit to go to the guy who made the CSS3 heart.. :-)